# MSAL Configuration for Microsoft Graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I want to get a token for Graph API using MSAL, but why my token Audience is always pointing out to my Client Id do I need to change the flow to get the token for MSAL? When I tried to get token from postman using password grant_type the audience is Microsoft graph.
here is my configuration

```
export const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider({
    auth: {
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId",
        clientId: "ClientId",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        redirectUri: window.location.origin,
        validateAuthority: true,

        // After being redirected to the "redirectUri" page, should user
        // be redirected back to the Url where their login originated from?
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    }
},
    {
        scope: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", "user.read"],
        extraQueryParameters: { domain_hint: 'organizations' }
    },
    {
        loginType: LoginType.Redirect,

        tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin + "/auth.html"
    },


)
```

and this is how I get the token

```
   const token = await authProvider.getIdToken();
        const idToken = token.idToken.rawIdToken;
```

and here is the request that got Microsoft Graph
[image]

where is the part that I'm wrong? Is it in my configuration or the way I obtain the token?

Comment: You are getting the id token rather than access token. See if `token.accessToken` or something like access token exists.

Comment: Please let us know which flow you are using in your application ? and just for confirmation are you able to get the token from postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: it is because you are getting an [ID Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims), which cannot be used to access a protected resource (such as MS Graph) because:

1. An ID Token's "audience" (`aud`) is the client application that requests it.
2. An ID Token does not have a scope (`scp`) claim, therefore cannot be exchanged for a resource in [v2 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison).

There is at least 1 more issue with your configuration:

> ```
> {
>     scope: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", "user.read"],
>     extraQueryParameters: { domain_hint: 'organizations' }
> },
> ```

The [/.default scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope) allows you to request all the static permissions you have added on Portal in one go. The `/.default` scope can not/should not be combined with other scopes, especially with `v2` scopes like `user.read`.

Read more about how to work with [resources and scopes here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/resources-and-scopes.md) (it's meant for MSAL.js, but the same principles apply).